# How do I create array from a single element in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I think the question is pretty straightforward, but still:

I have an object `obj`. How do I create array from this single object? Is it just `[obj]`

Comment: That's right. Just put it into array literal and you get an array of single element.

Comment: Yes. There are few other ways too but yours is already the most concise.

Comment: Just a tip for next time, I wouldn't pose this questions as React Native based, this is purely a JavaScript question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several ways to do this:

1. init an array and push obj inside:

   ```
   let array = [];
   array.push(obj);
   ```
2. init an array with obj:

   ```
   let array = [obj];
   ```
3. use `fill` function:

   ```
   let array = new Array(1).fill(obj);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
const array = [];

array.push(obj);
```

Output:

```
array = [obj]
```